# Import/export users/partners data in odoo

Tags: import, export, odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to export my odoo's user data... but I can't do it...

When I do the exportation, I've try to export all the data using the "Database Id" but when I try to import them again, I can't because I don't have the option "Database Id" in the options to import.

So, I also try to export the data using the "External Id", but, the relative Ids doesn't match, and It's imposibble to do it.

Also, I've try to export/import all the information from Settings > Sequences & Identifiers > External Identifiers because I thought it could be related, but It doesn't

So, What am I doing wrong??

Is there any chance to do a full exportation from the user-partner's information from my actual odoo to another??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate the whole database including models, fields, menu items, fields etc.
You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459975/data-transfer-from-one-database-to-other-database-in-odoo/46173101#46173101)

If you want to do through export and import than you have to validate it properly and have to remove the error. It will be helpful if you share the screenshot of your validation.

Answer (score -1):

Odoo automatically exports "External Id."(Which is self-generated if the record still does not have one). Then for import all you have to do is reference that "External Id." regardless of the id of the database.