# data transfer from one database to other database in odoo

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, odoo, odoo-8

I have one database. I want to transfer data from one database to new database. all tables have same fields into both databases. I can use export feature of openerp, but I need to maintain the relationship between odoo table and there is so many tables so I don't know which tables I can import first into a new database so it does not give any problem into other tables data import.
is there any that I can do this into easy and simple way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can take backup.

1. By hitting the given URL – server/web/database/manager.
2. By Import/Export and validation, functionality is given by Odoo.

•   **Backup->**  We can take the full backup of the system and store zip file in our system for a future update. For that, we have to hit this URL-  http://localhost:8069/web/database/manager

[image]
 - **Restore->** In a similar manner, we can restore the database by uploading the zipped file which we recently downloaded.

[image]